# Issues with webscraping in C#: Downloading and parsing zipped text files

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I am writing an webscraper, to do the download content from a website.

Traversing to the website/URL, triggers the creation of a temporary URL. This new URL has a zipped text file. This zipped file has to be downloaded and parsed.

I have written a **scraper** in C# using `WebClient` and its function `DownloadFileAsync()`. The zipped file is read from the designated location on a trapped `DownloadFileCompleted` event.

**My issue is** The Windows *Open/Save* dialog are triggered. This requires user input and the automation is disrupted.

Can you suggest a way to bypass the issue ?  I am cool with rewriting the code using any alternate libraries. :)

Thanks for reading

Comment: The term is "scraping", not "scrapping".

Comment: Your question doesn't really make any sense, nor is there enough information to answer it. If your problem is extracting your downloaded zip files, it depends on the format of the archive, but you'll want to integrate some command-line tool to extract it rather than having it open in Windows Explorer, which is what it sounds like you're doing...

Answer (score 0):

You can use ['HttpWebRequest'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to perform the request and save the streamed bytes to disk.

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(@"your url here");
request.Method=WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
var response = request.GetResponse();
using (var writeStream = new FileStream(@"path", FileMode.Create))
{
    using (var readStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        var readCount = readStream.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
        while (readCount > 0)
        {
            writeStream.Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
            readCount= readStream.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```